# #include <map> statement consuming lot of time for building my project using VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, build-process

One of my project is not building (after so many hours also) ... Its not proceeding further ...
The psuedocode is like this:

While building my project with Visual Studio 2008:

```
#pragma message("This is going to Include map.h")
#include <map>
#pragma message("The Included operation of map.h over")
```

For the above code snippet, the build output is showing the first message and the second message is not at all displaying (even after several hours). What might be caused this problem?. What could be wrong with the include `<map>` statement?

Comment: Does your project build faster without including <map>? I realise you will have to hack your code to remove references, but it might be worth a try just to see if you can get it to compile. Then try putting it back and see what difference it has.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using process explorer from [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) to see what files are being accessed during compilation. Could it be that you've got networked #include paths?

Comment: The VS 2008 Include files option has all the paths from local disk only. i.e., Tools ->Options->VC++ Directories -> Include files -> all the paths are from the local disk.

Can you elaborate on process explorer from sysinternals to see what files are being accessed during compilation. How to use?

Comment: In procexp, find the CL process that presumably is taking a long time. Frome the "view" menu, select "show lower pane"; Also View/Lower Pane View/Handles. Then you can see all the files that CL is accessing.

Answer (score 0):

@Edric

The VS 2008 Include files option has all the paths from local disk only. i.e., Tools ->Options->VC++ Directories -> Include files -> all the paths are from the local disk.

Can you elaborate on **process explorer from sysinternals to see what files are being accessed during compilation**. How to use?

Answer (score 0):

after several hours... doesn't sound like a compiler problem, more like a fault with the computer or filesystem. Open map in notepad and see if that takes time, run chkdsk to see if there are faults on the disk.

Comment: The map opening in Notepad is fast ... but building only consuming so much of time.

Comment: perhaps the .pch file creation is at fault, delete all temporary file and try again.